# Linguistic example with alternative gloss *and* translation

Tags: examples, gb4e, gloss

I'm writing a linguistics paper and I need to show alternative glosses and translations for a single example. I found the example here ([Align glosses in more than one language with gb4e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156066/align-glosses-in-more-than-one-language-with-gb4e)) which shows how to align multiple glosses, but I need to interpolate the translation lines -- in my case the alternative glossing shows different possible interpretations of the meaning -- throwing in an extra `\glt` makes errors. It should come out like this:

```
(1) Auto           uderzył dziecko
    car.nominative hit     child.accusative
    'The car hit the child.'
    car.accusative hit     child.nominative
    'The child hit the car.'
```

Is something like this possible with `gb4e` or `langsci-gb4e`? My go-to workaround has been to just repeat the numbered example, but I think it looks a bit stupid.

---

edit:
Responding to the comments -- it's not really a problem to solve, but a how-to type question. I'm adding minimal working example anyway, even though it shows how I currently have the code, not that which generates the desired output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex 
            \gll Auto uderzył dziecko. \\
            car.\textsc{nom} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{acc}\\
            \glt `The car hit the child.'
        \ex
            \gll Auto uderzył dziecko. \\
            car.\textsc{acc} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{nom} \\
            \glt `The child hit the car.''
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex
        \glll Auto uderzył dziecko. \\
        car.\textsc{nom} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{acc}\\
        \glt `The car hit the child.'
        car.\textsc{acc} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{nom} \\
        \glt `The child hit the car.''
\end{exe}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. As usual, it'd be easier to debug your code if you showed the code in question. PLease provide a Minimal Working Example that triggers the problem.

Comment: @Miyase There's not really anything to debug -- I can produce glossed examples, but not of the type showed in (1) in the OP. It's a "how-to" question, not a "what's wrong with my code" question.

Comment: I understand that, but with LaTeX a lot of details depend heavily on what your preamble contains. Some packages cannot be recommended if you're using, or aren't using, certain other packages, and so on.

Comment: @Miyase So, I'm looking for strategies that can achieve the desired result. Preferably utilizing the gb4e or langsci-gb4e packages. I can imagine many hackey ways to achieve desired output, but I'd prefer to keep the numbering, etc & not have to mess too much with the other examples that exist before / after this one in a relatively long document.

Comment: The glossing macros are designed to work with two lines, so adding a second gloss line without the original sentence being repeated isn't really possible. It would be a lot easier to repeat the sentence. You can still preserve a single number for the example. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Preserving the sentence is definitely not ideal. It's what I have now. Different numbers are ok -- I can refer to them in the text.

Comment: The other option if you want to have only one original sentence is two gloss lines then two translation lines. But interspersing gloss lines and translation lines isn't really possible.

Comment: @AlanMunn This is also not ideal.... anyway, I figured out a workaround. I'll post it in a minute.

Comment: @AlanMunn Since you provided the original \gliv command, do you think you could show how to add more lines to this trick?

Answer (score 2):

So I will answer my own question. Following the accepted answer in the post here ([Align glosses in more than one language with gb4e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156066/align-glosses-in-more-than-one-language-with-gb4e)), I defined (copy-pasted) a `\gliv` command in my preamblelike this, then group one gloss line inside curly brackets to make a translation line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\newbox\linefour
\newbox\wordfour
\def\gliv%                 % Introduces 4-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begin{flushleft}
     \ifx\@gsingle1% 
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \foursent
   }
\@ifundefined{eachwordfour}{\let\eachwordfour=\rmfamily}{\relax}   
\gdef\foursent#1\\ #2\\ #3\\ #4\\{% #1 = first line, #2 = second line, #3 = third, #4 = fourth
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#1 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#2 \\%
    \getwords(\linethree,\eachwordthree)#3 \\%
    \getwords(\linefour,\eachwordfour)#4 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
         \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
         \lastword{\eachwordthree}{\linethree}{\wordthree}%
         \lastword{\eachwordfour}{\linefour}{\wordfour}%
         \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{\unhbox\gline
                                    \hskip\glossglue
                                    \vtop{\box\wordone   % vtop was vbox
                                          \nointerlineskip
                                          \box\wordtwo
                                          \nointerlineskip
                                          \box\wordthree
                                          \nointerlineskip
                                          \box\wordfour
                                         }%
                                   }%
         \testdone
         \ifnotdone
    \repeat
    \egroup % matches \bgroup in \gloss
   \gl@stop}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex
        \gliv Auto uderzył dziecko. \\
        car.\textsc{nom} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{acc}\\
        {`The car hit the child.'} \\
        car.\textsc{acc} hit.3\textsc{sg} child.\textsc{nom} \\
        {`The child hit the car.'} \\
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

That seems to do the trick while maintaining my numbering and not screwing up other parts of the document.

Comment: So this doesn't actually work that well – the width of the whole translation is given between the first and second word on the example and gloss lines. I don't understand the code well enough to tweak it :(

Comment: You can solve this problem by wrapping the first translation line in `\rlap`. I.e., `\rlap{‘The car hit the child’}`.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn. And adding another line to your solution? I tried to follow the pattern - everywhere there's a sequence of lines with "one", "two", "three", "four", I added another line with "five", but it doesn't work. I don't understand the code well enough to tweak it beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

[image: gloss POC]

More or less a flexible(ish) stand-in for the `\gl...` commands.

As proof of concept, using expl3 sequences as set containers and a starting point, with:

- namespaces
- arbitrary user-choice line ending markers (e.g., `*/`)
- translation(s), for any line, split out by `glt` as a marker
- styling for parts of speech separated from the data

```
\mfsloadaseql[gloss]{ex2}{*/}{%
Auto uderzył dziecko. 
*/        car.nom hit.3sg child.acc
glt        `The car hit the child.' 
*/        car.acc hit.3sg child.nom 
glt        `The child hit the car.' 
}
```

Core MWE

First iteration code. The names of things can be changed, or wrapped behind an API - all the usual things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{xparse}

%squiggle
\newcommand\squiggle{%
\begin{center}
{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58}
\end{center}
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn



        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }


\tl_new:N \g_fc_namespace_tl


%------------------

%****************************************************
%* main commands
%****************************************************
\int_new:N \g_gloss_licount_int
\int_new:N \g_gloss_wordcount_int
\int_new:N \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int
\tl_new:N \g_fc_wnamespace_tl
\tl_new:N \g_fc_mylinenum_tl
\tl_new:N \g_gloss_currentline_tl
\tl_new:N \g_gloss_currentword_tl
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadwords } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=line number
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_wnamespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_wnamespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            \exp_args:Nnnx
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { ~ } 
            { #3 }

%   \seq_show:c 
%           { g_fc_line \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 

    \int_gset:Nn
            \g_gloss_wordcount_int
            {
                    \seq_count:c 
                            { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                
            }

%%%=
%%  \seq_use:cn
%%          { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl #2 _seq } 
%%          { | }
%%
%%  \tex_space:D (
%%  \int_use:N
%%          \g_gloss_wordcount_int
%%  \tex_space:D items for line #2)
}




%--------------------
\tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl
\tl_new:N \l_tmpd_tl
\tl_new:N \l_texttranslinenum_tl
\tl_new:N \l_texttransline_tl
\int_new:N \l_texttransline_int
\int_new:N \l_texttransloop_int
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaseql } { o m m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=sep
% 4=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
            
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { #3 } 
            { #4 }

%%=
%   \seq_show:c 
%           { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 




%-----
    \int_gset:Nn
            \g_gloss_licount_int
            {
                    \seq_count:c 
                            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                
            }


%%%%=
%%% \seq_use:cn
%%%         { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
%%%         { | }

%%%%=
%%% \tex_space:D (
%%% \int_use:N
%%%         \g_gloss_licount_int
%%%     \tex_space:D items)
    
    % words:
    \int_set:Nn
            \l_tmpa_int
            { 1 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn 
        { \l_tmpa_int } > { \g_gloss_licount_int } 
     {
%    xxx
     % split out any translation
    \tl_set:Nx 
            \l_texttranslinenum_tl   
            { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
            
    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq } 
            }

    \tl_set:Nx 
            \l_texttransline_tl      
            { 
                                    \seq_item:cn
                                { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                                { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }

                }

            
%   \exp_args:NNNx      
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq } 
            { glt } 
            { 
                \l_texttransline_tl
%                   \seq_item:cn
%                               { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
%                               { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
             }
     
     %=
%%  \seq_show:c 
%%          { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq }      
     
     % store the text
        \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_tmpb_tl
                    { 
%                           \seq_item:cn
%                                   { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
%                                   { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
                            \seq_item:cn
                                    { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq } 
                                    { 1 }

                     }
%       \tl_show:N
%                   \l_tmpb_tl
            \mfsloadwords   { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int    }{ \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl }
            \int_incr:N
                    \l_tmpa_int
     }


    % ===============================
    % box everything: (line,word) coord
    \int_set:Nn
            \l_tmpa_int
            { 1 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each line
        { \l_tmpa_int } > { \g_gloss_licount_int } 
     {
                    
                    \tl_set:Nx 
                            \g_fc_mylinenum_tl                  
                            { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
%           \seq_show:c
%                                           { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
                            
                            \exp_args:NNx
                    \int_set:Nn 
                            \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int
                            {
                                    \seq_count:c
                                            { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
                            }
%                   \int_show:N
%                           \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int
                            
                    \int_set:Nn
                    \l_tmpb_int
                    { 1 }
                    
                            
                    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each word
                    { \l_tmpb_int } > { \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int } 
                    {
%---start
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentline_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentword_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }

    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
            { \box_new:c
                    { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box } 
            }
            
%xxx-start
%   \hbox_gset:cn 
%           { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
%           {
%               \seq_item:cn
%                       { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
%                       { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }
%           }

    \tl_set:Nx
                \l_tmpc_tl
            {
                \seq_item:cn
                        { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
                        { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }
            }


%vvv
        \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\.) }
                { \c{scshape} \0 }
                \l_tmpc_tl

    \hbox_gset:cn 
            { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
            {
                \tl_use:N
                            \l_tmpc_tl
            }


%------------------------ end compound gloss

%%%%=           
%%%         % show:
%%%         \tex_par:D
%%% \box_use:c
%%%         { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box } ~ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int --  \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int :
%%% \the\box_wd:c
%%%         { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
%%%         .
%---end
                        \int_incr:N 
                                \l_tmpb_int
                    }   
        \int_incr:N 
                \l_tmpa_int
        }   
    
    % ===============================
  % find widest box by word number
                    \int_set:Nn
                    \l_tmpb_int
                    { 1 }
                    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each word
                    { \l_tmpb_int } > { \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int }  %%%
                    {
                    
%%                  \tl_set:Nx 
%%                          \g_fc_mylinenum_tl                  
%%                          { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
%%%         \seq_show:c
%%%                                         { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
%%                          
%%                          \exp_args:NNx
%%                  \int_set:Nn 
%%                          \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int
%%                          {
%%                                  \seq_count:c
%%                                          { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
%%                          }
%%%                 \int_show:N
%%%                         \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int
                            
    \int_set:Nn
            \l_tmpa_int
            { 1 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each line
        { \l_tmpa_int } > { \g_gloss_licount_int } 
                {
%---start
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentline_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentword_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }

    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }
            { \dim_new:c
                    { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }
                }


%IF
%\exp_args:xNx
\dim_compare:nNnT
            {
                    \box_wd:c
                            { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
            }
            >
            { 
                    \dim_use:c
                            { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }
            }
            {
%               SET WORDXWIDTH-EQ
                    \dim_set:cn 
                                { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }
                                {
                                \box_wd:c
                                            { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }

                                }               
            }
%%  \cs_if_free:cT
%%          { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
%%          { \box_new:c
%%                  { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box } 
%%          }
%%  \hbox_gset:cn 
%%          { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
%%          {
%%              \seq_item:cn
%%                      { g_fc_line \g_fc_wnamespace_tl \g_fc_mylinenum_tl   _seq } 
%%                      { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }
%%
%%          }
            
%%          % show:
%%          \tex_par:D
%%  \box_use:c
%%          { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box } ~ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int --  \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int :
%%  \the\box_wd:c
%%          { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
%%          .
%%%---end
                        \int_incr:N 
                                \l_tmpa_int
                    }   
                \int_incr:N 
                        \l_tmpb_int


%%%%=
%%%Widest 
%%%\g_gloss_currentword_tl
%%%=
%%%                 \dim_use:c
%%%                         { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }

        }   
    
  
    % ===============================
  % set each nth word to widest width
%               \tex_par:D %=
\leavevmode\tex_space:D \\%=
%               \tex_par:D %=
    \int_set:Nn
            \l_tmpa_int
            { 1 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each line
        { \l_tmpa_int } > { \g_gloss_licount_int } 
                    {
    \makebox[1.2in]{} %=                                    
    
    %+++
    %+++
                    \int_set:Nn
                    \l_tmpb_int
                    { 1 }
                    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each word
                    { \l_tmpb_int } > { \g_gloss_wordsonthisline_int }  %%%
                    
                {
%---start
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentline_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_gloss_currentword_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int }

\box_gset_wd:cn
            { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
            { 
                    \dim_use:c
                            { g_gloss_wordwidth\g_gloss_currentword_tl _dim }
            }
                \int_incr:N 
                        \l_tmpb_int
                        
                    \box_use:c %=
                                { g_gloss_line\g_gloss_currentline_tl word\g_gloss_currentword_tl _box }
                        \tex_space:D %=
                        \tex_space:D %=
                    }   
                        \int_incr:N 
                                \l_tmpa_int
%               \tex_par:D \space%=
%%\seq_item:cn
%%                                  { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\l_texttranslinenum_tl _seq }
    \int_set:Nn 
            \l_texttransline_int
            {
\seq_count:c
                                    { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\g_gloss_currentline_tl _seq }
            }
%   \int_show:N 
%           \l_texttransline_int
            
            \int_compare:nNnT
                            { \l_texttransline_int } > { 1 }
                            {
                                %loop through the translations
                    \int_set:Nn
                    \l_texttransloop_int
                    { 2 }
                    \int_do_until:nNnn % for each translation
                    { \l_texttransloop_int } > { \l_texttransline_int }     %%%
                    {
                        \\%=
                            \makebox[1.2in]{} %=                                    
                            \seq_item:cn
                                    { g_fc_texttrans \g_fc_namespace_tl #2\g_gloss_currentline_tl _seq }
                                    { \l_texttransloop_int }
                        
                        \int_incr:N
                                \l_texttransloop_int
                                
                    }           
                                
                                }
            
 \\%=
        }   
  
    
}


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }

%   \seq_show:c 
%           { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 


}

%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaprop } { o m +m } { % 1=NS, 2=prop name, 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }

    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _prop }
            { \prop_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _prop } 
            }
    \prop_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _prop } 
    \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _prop } 
            { #3 }

}






\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\mfsloadaseql[gloss]{ex1}{*/}{%
gef hundinum matinn
*/    gje hunden maten
*/    give {the dog} {the food}
*/    gib {dem Hunde} {das Essen}
}

\squiggle

\mfsloadaseql[gloss]{ex2}{*/}{%
Auto uderzył dziecko. 
*/        car.nom hit.3sg child.acc
glt        `The car hit the child.' 
*/        car.acc hit.3sg child.nom 
glt        `The child hit the car.' 
}

\squiggle

\mfsloadaseql[tale]{ex1}{xx}{%
The cat sat on the mat.
xx        article.def noun.nom verb.3pps .prep .def .loc
glt        Phonological congruence
glt                     Contrary to The quick brown fox
glt        Single syllables
glt                     Feline habitude 
}

\end{document}
```