Multilingual interlinear gloss between Russian Cyrillic and Indonesian Latin alphabets in gb4e
I want to perform a multilingual interlinear gloss in gb4e between Russian and Indonesian. Previous attempt had failed to make sure that the glosses, transliteration, and the original text to align with each other.
Here is the tex document:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex
\gll \?{Путин} \?{опроверг} \?{дискриминацию} \?{геев} \?{в} \?{России} \\
putin oproverg diskriminatsiju gejev v rossii\\
putin membantah-MASK.LAMP.PERF diskriminasi-AKU gay-JAM.GEN di rusia-PREP \
\trans "Putin membantah adanya diskriminasi terhadap kelompok gay di Rusia"

\end{exe}

\end{document}

Typeset of document:

In the gloss, there are four lines:

The Russian text in Cyrillic
The transliteration of Cyrillic to Latin
The linguistic gloss
The translation in Indonesian

The problem here is that the linguistic gloss does not line with the Russian text and the transliteration.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Alan Munn provided a great answer for this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156066/align-glosses-in-more-than-one-language-with-gb4e

Yes @AlanMunn, thank you :)
